# In app purchase not work after submitting app

Tags: ios

I created my app and add the in-app-purchase items.Before I submit App,  I tested the purchase function lots of times using test user on iphone device, it worked fine. But after I submit the app, all purchase item was not working, and this cause my app be rejected.( I am sure the I selected all iap production before submit)
Now neither the requesting product information nor the buy transaction is not working. But both worked fine before sumbitting the app. I'v investigated it for several days and cannot solve the problem.
Really appreciate if you can help.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Just do make sure: You did look that you unique app id you used for testing in app purchases was also used for the provisioning profile?

Cheers, Jörg

Comment: ah, and the following stack overflow answer might be useful too: [Which Provisioning Profile to use when testing In App Purchase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074123/which-provisioning-profile-to-use-when-testing-in-app-purchase)

Comment: Yes, if you mean the bundle id.

Comment: hm, so far then I am also lost. I can only suggest you go trough the list of the link I added to the commend. sorry. hope anyone else answers that .... :/

Comment: I got the reasons, the app Id I was using has wildcard and cannot be used for in app purchase. But I don't know why it worked before submitting...Thank Joerg !

Comment: ok, it is really strange that it did work before. however, good that you could resolve the issue!